# Can't copy *some* files with alternate data streams from Windows to Samba 4.7.6

Tags: windows, samba

My DIY Ubuntu 18.04LTS NAS is running Samba 4.7.6.

I'm facing the following issue: I can't copy *some* files that have NTFS alternate data streams from Windows (10, latest version 1809 release build) to a Samba share, while this works fine for *other* files with ADS:

```
PS C:/tmp/withads> ls


    Directory: C:\tmp\withads

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2015-03-12    19:33            700 nok.url
-a----        2009-10-13    07:34            216 ok.url

PS C:/tmp/withads> get-item ok.url -stream *

PSPath        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\tmp\withads\ok.url::$DATA
PSParentPath  : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\tmp\withads
PSChildName   : ok.url::$DATA
PSDrive       : C
PSProvider    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
PSIsContainer : False
FileName      : C:\tmp\withads\ok.url
Stream        : :$DATA
Length        : 216

PSPath        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\tmp\withads\ok.url:favicon
PSParentPath  : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\tmp\withads
PSChildName   : ok.url:favicon
PSDrive       : C
PSProvider    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
PSIsContainer : False
FileName      : C:\tmp\withads\ok.url
Stream        : favicon
Length        : 894


PS C:/tmp/withads> copy ok.url //pnjnas/public
PS C:/tmp/withads> get-item nok.url -stream *

PSPath        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\tmp\withads\nok.url::$DATA
PSParentPath  : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\tmp\withads
PSChildName   : nok.url::$DATA
PSDrive       : C
PSProvider    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
PSIsContainer : False
FileName      : C:\tmp\withads\nok.url
Stream        : :$DATA
Length        : 700

PSPath        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\tmp\withads\nok.url:favicon
PSParentPath  : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\tmp\withads
PSChildName   : nok.url:favicon
PSDrive       : C
PSProvider    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
PSIsContainer : False
FileName      : C:\tmp\withads\nok.url
Stream        : favicon
Length        : 17542


PS C:/tmp/withads> copy nok.url //pnjnas/public
copy : There is not enough space on the disk : '\\pnjnas\public\nok.url'
At line:1 char:1
+ copy nok.url //pnjnas/public
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Any clue?

If that would be related to xattr support / ext4 limitations, wouldn't that affect *all* files?

Answer (score 1):

If this is really true, that's your issue:

> ```
> copy nok.url //pnjnas/public
> copy : There is not enough space on the disk : '\\pnjnas\public\nok.url'
> ```

Comment: Of course not... but I forgot to mention that... there are 50GB+ free on that filesystem.